# Why don't I have the HM Cut after defeating Misty? Is this a bug?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I had a bug and I cannot find any reference to it online.

I started Pokemon Blue and after the second gym (Misty) I realised that I needed to learn "Cut" to progress. I looked in my inventory and realised that I had no HM's. Shouldn't I have had 2 at that stage?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be closed. The question is asking about the progress of the game (even if they are mistaking it for a bug).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be missing the [correct path](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Appendix:Red_and_Blue_walkthrough/Section_5), and not encountering a bug.

To progress after beating Misty, you must head north to Routes 24 & 25 and help Bill. For your efforts he will give you the S.S. Ticket. Head back towards Cerulean, and then head south to Route 5, and take the underground path to Route 6 and Vermilion City beyond. From Vermilion City, you must go south to the docks, and board the S.S. Anne using the ticket Bill gave you. After you help the Captain (be sure to grab everything from the ship while you are on it, as it will be gone permanently after) he will give you HM01 Cut.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that to initially get out of Cerulean City, you need to go through the house that was robbed by Team Rocket. After you've received the SS Ticket and defeated Misty, the police officer steps out of the doorway, allowing you access.